# How exactly a CTRL^C passes a signal to process

Tags: bash, terminal, signals, pseudoterminal

I'm trying to figure out how exactly CTRL^C sends a SIGINT to a process.
Let's consider a pseudo-terminal system.  I'll write what I know (or think I know lol) and please add/replace where needed:

The players are:

- Xterm - This is a user space program that reads from the keyboard (using the X window system) and renders a picture to the screen. Every character it gets from the keyboard is passed to the `pty master` .
- User process - the user process that runs as a foreground job of the terminal. Usually when opening a Xterm it runs bash or some other shell program as this user process.
- PTY device - This is a character device that the user process is connected to as its `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`. Everything that's written by the process to `stdout` is processed by the TTY driver and its line discipline, and passed as input to the maser side, and vice versa.

I don't mind at the moment how exactly the kernel passes the signal to the process once the line discipline/TTY driver understands that it should send such a signal to the process. What I'm interested in is how, after I press `CTRL^Z` on my keyboard, the Xterm (Which is the process that reads this key presses) passes this information to the `pty master`

### EDIT

Thanks for the answers. I welcome you to response on [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629172/sending-a-signal-to-a-process-using-a-pty-master) where I actually tried to simulate this by writing `0x3` to a PTY master and see what happens in the slave. Could you guys respond to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xterm` just writes the `^C` character (ASCII 3) to the pseudo-tty master, something you can easily simulate with `script` (another program which, just like `xterm`, is managing a master pseudo-tty):

```
{ sleep 1; printf '\x03'; } | script -qc 'trap "echo SIGINT ma tuer; exit 1" I
NT; cat' /dev/null
^CSIGINT ma tuer
```